# Navigationview Custom Submenu view

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

As shown in picture can i change submenu's UI? With dynamic code. Adding SubMenu1 ,Submenu2 ...etc with dynamic arraylist and

```
menu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(menu.size() - 1);
 topChannelMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Sub items");
 mi = menu.getItem(menu.size() - 1);

 for (int i = 0; i < projectList.size(); i++) {
     mi = topChannelMenu.add(1, i, i, "").setActionView(R.layout.item_project_menu);
}
```

[image]

Comment: post the menu file also

Comment: i am not using any menu file

Comment: use the menu file and create submenu using icon

Comment: refer this and add icon to item for subtitle

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/12648/navigationview-android

Comment: but i need to add items under "Sub items" and that also dynamically